# Setting the job priority in YARN with oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, oozie-workflow

We trigger our spark jobs with oozie workflow. There are situation where we need to set high priority for some of jobs which will submit to yarn queue.
I have tried to set `mapreduce.job.priority=HIGH` in oozie property before submitting a job, but Application Priority : 0 is still showing when I check yarn job status.

How to set a high property?

Comment: Spark doesn't use mapreduce properties... Check the Spark on YARN docs where you can see you can set the YARN queue, for example